# How to Implement BookMark in jsf1.2?

Tags: bookmarks, jsf-1.2

In my application using `JSF1.2` I have two jsp pages  one is `allemployee.jsp` in which I placed a `<h:dataTable>` with `100 rows` . Each contains employee's `name`,`phone No`,`experience` and so on... and the second page is
`detail.jsp` where I am displaying single employee's detail. In each row of `allemployee.jsp` there have a `<h:commandLink>` with value `employee's name`. After clicking this `<h:commandLink>` it displays corresponding
employee's detail in `detail.jsp` . Now in `detail.jsp` I have a `<h:commandButton>` named `Go Back` . I want after clicking this `button` user will come into the previous position of `allemployee.jsp` from where he/she
jumped to `detail.jsp`.

My `allemployee.jsp` looks like :

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable id="employeeList" value="#{employeelist.employees}" var="employee" cellspacing="60">
        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{msg.list}" /></f:facet>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{msg.name}"/></f:facet>
            <h:commandLink value="#{employee.name}" action="#{employeelist.getaction}" actionListener="#{employeelist.sendToDetail}">
                <f:param id="NamE" value="#{employee.name}" name="NamE"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{msg.phn}" /></f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{employee.phNo}" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{msg.experience}" /></f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{employee.experiance}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

My `detail.jsp` looks like :

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.name}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{detail.employee.name}" />

    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.phn}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{detail.employee.phNo}" />

    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.experience}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{detail.employee.experiance}" />
</h:panelGrid>
    <h:outputLink value="/allemployee.jsp#paramName">
        <f:param name="paramName" value="#{detail.employee.name}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Go Back" />
    </h:outputLink>
```

`employeelist` Bean looks like :

```
public class EmployeeListController implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6930161072142091260L;

private List<EmployeeModel> employees;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Service service = new Service();
    this.employees = service.getAll();
}

public void sendToDetail(ActionEvent ev) {
    String name = (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("NamE");
    for (EmployeeModel employee : employees) {
        if (employee.getName().equals(name)) {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            req.setAttribute("employe", employee);
        }
    }
}

public String goback(){
    return "allemployee";
}

public String getaction() {
    return "detail";
}
//getter & setter of  employees.
```

}
In class `EmployeeModel` there are variables `name`,`phNo` ,`experience` and getters & setters.
In class `Service` I set all employees details.

My `detail` Bean is looks like :

```
public class DetailController implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8632585974603579268L;

private EmployeeModel employee = new EmployeeModel();
private String paramName;
public DetailController() {

}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    this.employee = (EmployeeModel) req.getAttribute("employe");
    this.paramName = employee.getName();
    }

// getter & setter employee and paramName.
```

}

`faces-config` is like :

```
<managed-bean>
<managed-bean-name>detail</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>com.edfx.controller.DetailController</managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
 <managed-property>
    <property-name>paramName</property-name>
    <value>#{param.paramName}</value>
 </managed-property>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
<managed-bean-name>employeelist</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>com.edfx.controller.EmployeeListController</managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
<display-name>allemployee.jsp</display-name>
<from-view-id>/allemployee.jsp</from-view-id>
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>detail</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/detail.jsp</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

How can I fulfill my requirement? Any pointer will be very helpful to me. Thanks,

Comment: Instead of making `employeelist` a `request` scoped bean, try `session` scope and see if it fulfills your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .Where and how I set bookmark in `allemployee.jsp` ??

Comment: "I want after clicking this button user will come into the previous position of allemployee.jsp" you mean just in the same scroll position you were before jumping into the other page? If you want that the only way I see is to show the employer details in other browser window/tab.